# How do you read 24 × 7 service?

Tags: pronunciation

24 × 7 service store is a store which provides the 24 hour service and 7 days for the whole week. I am wondering how native speakers read **24 × 7 service store**? For example, we provide 24 × 7 service. Thanks!

Comment: You should add some examples of such usage that you found. Also where you are or expect to see this. "service" only meaning they are open for business?

Comment: @user3169 for example, I see some drug stores where they provide the 24×7 service. Usually, they put a sign like 24×7, or 24 hours×7, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly: people read 24x7 as `twenty-four seven`.